# Sort records based on specific value postresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have three tables
1)fruits -- id, name
2)countries -- id, name
3)fruit_countries -- id, fruit_id(fk), country_id(fk)

In my fruits table I want to show fruits which are not present in a specific country on top.

I used

```
select
    distinct(fruits.*),case when fruit_countries.country_id = xx then 1 else 0 end
from
    "fruits"
left join fruit_countries on
    fruit_countries.fruit_id = fruits.id
order by case when fruit_countries.country_id = xx then 1 else 0 end
```

the problem is since a fruit can be linked to multiple countries I get few fruits records on top of the list when they are present in country xx and some-other countries.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=10ec3b379a949e35f32845355496e17d)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM fruits f
LEFT JOIN fruit_countries fc ON f.id = fc.fruit_id
ORDER BY bool_or(fc.country_id = 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fc.fruit_id)
```

You can use the `bool_or()` window function in the `ORDER BY` clause. This checks if there is any records per `fruit_id` group (partition) with the requested `country_id`. If not, it will be ordered first.

However, the normal `ORDER BY` orders the `NULL` records to bottom. But, obviously they are not assigned to the specific `country_id` as well (they are `NULL` because there are assigned to no country), you could add `NULLS FIRST` to the `ORDER BY` clause, to order these fruits to top everytime.

Comment: Changed answer because misunderstood the problem first.

Comment: I think it is working. And if I want to do the opposite order i.e fruit available at a specific country first then it should be add 'DESC' to the 'order by' ?

Comment: Yes, correct (and with NULLS LAST or without it)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 6.1 you can use

```
Fruit.where.missing(:countries) + Fruit.includes(:countries)
```